# Double Decks summation reindexing

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I'm self studying combinatorics with Springer's *Combinatorics and Graph Theory* and am having trouble understanding the summation manipulations used to derive a formula for the generating function that represents "how many ways to select $m$ items from $n$ different items, where each item can be selected at most twice". He denotes that quantity by $t_{n,m}$, and derives it by generating functions and the binomial theorem.

> $$\begin{align}
> G_n(x) & = (1+(x+x^2))^n \\
> & =  \sum_k\binom{n}{k}(x+x^2)^k \\
> & = \sum_k\binom{n}{k}x^k \sum_j\binom{k}{j}x^j \\
> & = \sum_k\sum_j\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{j}x^{j+k} \\
> & = \sum_m \left( \sum_j\binom{n}{m-j}\binom{m-j}{j}\right)\,x^m,\\
> \end{align}
> $$
>   where we obtained the last line by substituting $m$ for $j+k$. Therefore,
>
> $$\begin{align}
> t_{m,n} = \sum_{j=0}^{\lfloor{m/2}\rfloor} \binom{n}{m-j}\binom{m-j}{j}
> \end{align}$$

I can understand everything up to the last two lines. How can you change the outer sum index to be a function of the inner sum, when the inner sum itself is a function of k (assuming $k$ becomes $m-j$)? I tried to rework everything by writing the indexes explicitly, but couldn't work out how this $m$ was introduced.

Also on the last line, how did he introduce the $\lfloor{m/2}\rfloor$ to calculate a specific coefficient? (I assume this step will become clear if I understand the previous one)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next to last is just applying [Cauchy's product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) (the expression for the coefficient of the product of $\sum_{i \ge 0} a_i z^i$ and $\sum_{i \ge 0} b_i z^i$) "in reverse". To explain the $\lfloor m / 2 \rfloor$ limit in the last expression, just take the sum as an infinite sum over $j \ge 0$ (as written in the derivation), and check where the sum stops due to a binomial coefficient becoming 0 when $m$ is odd and even.